# How do I connect to NearlyFreeSpeech-hosted MySQL database remotely?

Tags: mysql, navicat, nearlyfreespeech

What URL/hostname/IP address to I use to connect to a MySQL database hosted by NearlyFreeSpeech? What port?

I want to use Navicat or a similar program to do this. I know the username and password.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is probably best obtained from their online help, or directed to their technical support channels.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key is to use SSH (Secure Shell) using your database software - most hosting services do NOT allow unsecured access, including NearlyFreeSpeech, so SSH is the way to go.

In your database software, you should see multiple options to login via "standard", "socket", and "SSH".

Your SSH details can be found in your NFS "Site" Tab, under "FTP/SFTP/SSH Information". Don't forget to check to see if SSH is enabled, and make sure you note that the SSH loginID includes an "_domainname" following your usual non-SSH login.

Example connection:

```
MySQL Host: example.db  
Username: john123  
Password: *******  
Database: (optional - leave blank)  
Port: (optional- default 3306)

SSH Host: ssh.phx.nearlyfreespeech.net    
SSH User: John123_mygreatsite   
SSH Password: *******  
SSH Port: (optional - leave blank)
```